# PostgresSQL - Loop through daily Select statement for end of month reporting

Tags: postgresql, datetime

PostgreSQL 9.4.5

The following select statement I run every night at 11:55 PM.  I want to run a monthly query (or function) that loops through the following query based on a hard-coded start_date and end_date.  The query must process the results on a day-by-day basis.  Ultimately I want to see how many lost sheep we have in a given month.

Purpose: Lost Sheep-  We are looking for users that attempt to login to MySoftware and are unsuccessful for an entire day.

```
*The IP address is compared against other login attempts that may be successful the rest of the day.  In the event of a login failure, the query should look into the ip address and verify that no successful logins happened from that same IP address within the day.

SELECT  DISTINCT l.username, l.ip
FROM login l
                    WHERE
                        l.ip NOT IN 
                            (SELECT  l.ip
                            FROM login l
                            WHERE 
                                date_trunc('day', l."time") = current_date
                                AND l.succeeded = 'TRUE')
                        AND date_trunc('day', l."time") = current_date
                        AND l.succeeded = 'False'


fields in Table logins
 1. id  -int
 2. username --character varying(255)
 3. ip -- character varying (255)
 4. time -- timestamp without time zone
 5. succeeded -- boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select date_trunc('day', l.time) as 'day', l.username, l.ip
from login l
where date_trunc('month', l.time) = '2015-09-01'
group by 1, 2, 3
having not bool_or(succeded)
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, and your answer puts me closer.  Your suggestion does give me a list of all the failed logins by day for the month...  However, I need to have logic that looks at the 'ip address' of the user and verifies that the user from that ip hasn't logged in successfully for that day.  

Sometimes our users forget their username, and after failing remember their correct username and then login successfully.  If you notice in my query provided their is logic to handle those logins and eliminate them from the list.